# Custom UIButton isSelected background color not working as expected (IOS / Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, background, uibutton

I have a custom `UIButton` class where this code is not working as expected:

```
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.white
        }
    }
```

When I set `isSelected` in code, the background does NOT change... it stays white.  I know that the actual boolean value `isSelected` true/false IS actually being toggled properly, though.

The code inside didSet IS executing (I have verified with print debugging), but somehow the background is not being set.

Interestingly, I have also overridden the `isHighlighted` method in exactly the same way, which works fine.

Here is the full code for the custom button class.  ***FEEL FREE TO CUT/PASTE THIS INTO YOUR XCODE AND PLAY WITH IT***:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class PlusMinusButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable
    var highlightColor: UIColor = .yellow { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var fillColor: UIColor = .yellow { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var strokeColor: UIColor = .yellow { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    @IBInspectable
    var plusOrMinus: Bool = true { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }


    func getPath() -> UIBezierPath {

        let G = bounds.width / 5

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        switch plusOrMinus {

        case true:

            let startPoint = CGPoint(x:2*G,y:G)
            path.move(to: startPoint)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:2*G,y:2*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:G,y:2*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:G,y:3*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:2*G,y:3*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:2*G,y:4*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:4*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:3*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G,y:3*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G,y:2*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:2*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:3*G,y:G))
            path.addLine(to: startPoint)

        case false:

            let startPoint = CGPoint(x:G,y:3*G)

            path.move(to: startPoint)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G,y:3*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:4*G,y:2*G))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:G,y:2*G))
            path.addLine(to: startPoint)

        }

        path.close()

        return path

    }

    // see how is method is exactly the same as the next?  weird, huh?
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? highlightColor : UIColor.white
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("This line of code is executed!!")
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.white
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let path = getPath()

        fillColor.setFill()

        path.fill()

        strokeColor.setStroke()

        path.stroke()

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!  I bet it's something real dumb!  Merp! :B

Comment: give the code where you set it selected. Like in your view or controller

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but that should not be necessary since "I know that the actual boolean value .isSelected true/false IS actually being toggled properly, though.  The code inside didSet IS executing (I have verified with print debugging), but somehow the background is not being set."

Comment: Can you try to set background color in willSet method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading documentation of [isSelected](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618203-isselected), [isHighlighted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618231-ishighlighted)and [setNeedsDisplay()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay) my understanding is, after toggling highlighted value, it automatically call an update/redraw process of UIControl. For isSelected toggling this is not guaranteed for all controls. I think UIButton is one of those.

**Updated Solution:**
One thing I missed is that, whenever you Tapp your button value of isHighlighted changes to true and when tap ends to changes back to false. So in your case whenever tap ends it changes back to `backgroundcolor = UIColor.white`. For the fix, I have given priority to highLighted bool and after that to isSelected bool to set back ground colour. Please check below code

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor =  isHighlighted ? highlightColor : (isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.white)
        }
    }

override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.white
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
```

**Invalid:**

```
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.white
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks again for the effort.  Does not seem to work.  This is my fault ultimately, of course. :)

Comment: If you like, you can cut paste this class right into your Xcode.

Comment: might have found your problem. Going in a meeting right now. Will post again in 30 mins

Comment: You're a champion.  SOLVED THE MYSTERY... THANKS!

Comment: PS - the part you mark as 'invalid' is actually still the same.  Also, 'setNeedsDisplay()' is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to update a ui component on runtime. I think u need execute code on main thread at run time. Try this:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {

    didSet {

        print("This line of code is executed!!")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.backgroundColor = self.isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.white
        }
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    self.tintColor = .clear

    let path = getPath()

    fillColor.setFill()

    path.fill()

    strokeColor.setStroke()

    path.stroke()

}
```

Do not forgot to set tintColor to clear otherwise you see a blue square dot upon button.

Working...! Tested the Code on Xcode 9.3 with Swift 4.0.2

[image: OutPut colors for buttons]

Answer (score 0):

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let path = getPath()

    fillColor.setFill()

    path.fill()

    strokeColor.setStroke()

    path.stroke()

  //ADD below line 

   self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that... tried but did not work.  I understand the concept of why this might work, but this is why I included the statement, "Interestingly, I have also overridden the isHighlighted method in exactly the same way, which works fine."

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution to this.
.toggle() is available as of Swift 4.2

```
class Button: UiButton {
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        isSelected.toggle()
        backgroundColor = isSelected ? .blue : .red
    }
}
```